# Docker image size doesn’t make sense

Tags: docker, docker-image

I’ve created a ubuntu:bionic base image on my computer. Originally super large size but I deleted 80% of the content by running container and then committing. If I got to root directory and do “du -sh”, it said disk usage 4.5GB. Curious enough, the size of docker image when I do "docker images’ show 11 GB. After pushing to docker hub, I see that it’s 3.34 GB. So I thought perhaps it cleaned up something before compressing? I ran the new image, deleted some more content, commit, and pushed again. This time, “du–sh” said 3.0 GB, “docker images” still said 11GB and docker hub also 3.34 GB. Clearly it is compressing the 11GB file and not the 3.0GB content I’m expecting. Is there a easy way to “clean up” the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker images are built from layers. When you add a new layer, it doesn't remove the previous layers, it just adds a new one, rather like a new Git commit—the history is still there.

That means when you deleted the content, you made it invisible but it's still there in earlier layers.

You can see the layers and their sizes with `docker history yourimagename`.

Your options:

1. Make sure files you don't need don't make it in the first place, e.g. with `.dockerignore`.
2. Use a multi-stage build to create new image from the old one with only the files you need. https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: The second option worked. I created a new dockerfile with 3 lines: FROM <BASE IMAGE>, WORKDIR /, and COPY --from=<OVERSIZED IMAGE> / ./ and the build was successful.